# How can i get Crystal Reports to list items horizontaly

Tags: crystal-reports

The owner wants a report contradictory to common design.
Say I have a list of States, Those States all have Cities.  He wants the states to go down the left and the cities to extend out to the right in columns. There is to structure to the number of cities going side ways.
His point is that Excel has a function to invert a lists direction so why not in crystal.

Please help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to solve this by simply inserting a CrossTab where rows are based on State and columns based on City.

Otherwise, you would need to Group the report by State and use a string variable to concatenate cities (that are not already in the string variable).

Comment: Thanks but I tried a Cross Tab and it is only a set number of columns. I believe what I am trying to do is not possible but had to ask.   The list to the righ is variable in size.  Some rows may have 5 columns and some rows may have 20 columns and any place in-between.